# Fade out of questions?

Tags: support

Recently I noticed questions on the front page that appear faded out:

[image: screenshot of Academia front page]

What is that supposed to indicate? Is it some new feature and I missed the announcement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because it contains tags that you have marked to be ignored.

More details on [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-watched-tags-and-ignored-tags-do) that explain it:

> ## Ignored Tags
>
> ...
> By default, questions with these tags are shown faded; they are still visible but less prominent. It is possible to hide them completely, for more details see: [How do I hide posts matching my ignored tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23811)

Comment: Thanks. I must have marked [tag:application] by accident. I certainly didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem. You saved my eyes. (I thought I should go see my eye doctor).